# Getting a error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: while trying to open a file

Tags: python

In a Folder called Assignment Parser, I've my ***parsing.py*** file along with a ***auth.txt*** file. Trying to open this ***auth.txt*** file. But getting an error that says :

```
(base) C:\Users\Ajay\Desktop\Python\Assignment Parser>python parsing.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parsing.py", line 27, in <module>
    main()
  File "parsing.py", line 8, in main
    file = open(file_path / "auth.txt","r")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Ajay\\Desktop\\Python\\Assignment Parser\\auth.txt'
```

**Code:**

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

def main():
    # read file
    # C:\Users\Ajay\Desktop\Python\Assignment Parser\
    file_path = Path("C:/Users/Ajay/Desktop/Python/Assignment Parser/")
    file = open(file_path / "auth.txt","r")
    # file = open("auth.txt", "r")
    lines = file.readlines()
    file.close()
```

Where is this going wrong? PFA for the screenprint.

[image]

Comment: Did you try it with the uncommented line (which should try the current working directory)? Does the file really exist?

Comment: Edited my post for the screenprint. File exists. @glglgl

Comment: @AjayBhagchandani Add this code above the file open line `print(os.listdir(file_path))`, lets see if it is listing the files inside the folder or not.

Comment: Ohk. got it. on using your line, I'm getting my "auth.txt" file printed as "auth.log". This   might be the reason. Thanks for helping @CodeIt

Comment: @AjayBhagchandani I had that doubt. That's why i asked you to try that. Anyway, I'm glad that it helped.

Comment: To phrase it another way, you omitted the first step of setting up a useful Windows profile: to have the file extensions displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

def main():
    # read file
    # C:\Users\Ajay\Desktop\Python\Assignment Parser\
    file_path = Path("C:/Users/Ajay/Desktop/Python/Assignment Parser/")
    file = open(os.path.join(file_path, "auth.txt"), "r")
    # file = open("auth.txt", "r")
    lines = file.readlines()
    file.close()
```

Comment: The problem is obviously not the path translation, because the file path which is tried is visible in the exception.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in file extension, I see `parsing` has .py extension but `auth` is not

please try `file = open(file_path / "auth", "r")`  again (just delete `.txt` extension)

Comment: Yeah, OP knows that it is not a `.py` file. OP trying to open `auth.txt` file. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57441921/getting-a-error-filenotfounderror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-while-t/57442070#comment101360308_57441921).

Comment: please try `file = open(file_path / "auth", "r")`  again (just delete `.txt` extension)

Comment: The problem is already solved. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57441921/getting-a-error-filenotfounderror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-while-t/57442070#comment101360308_57441921)

Answer (score 0):

As you have your python file in same folder as your text file. You can directly use below code.

```
def main():
     file = open("./auth.txt")
     lines = file.readlines()
     file.close()
```

Also make sure, your syder working directory is set to this folder path "C:/Users/Ajay/Desktop/Python/Assignment Parser"

Comment: The problem is not with the path because the file path which is tried is visible in the exception.